# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint for every Second Record that i try to save in a loop

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

Now I have read many threads addressing this issue but my issue is:

I'm trying to save multiple Customers in a loop> The First Customer is getting Saved but the next customer it fails. Now I tried this with multiple Set of Customers every time when it tries to save a customer Excluding the First Customer I'm getting the following error message:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_COPS.Address_GraphiteGTCCore.YesNoQuestion_IsPrimaryId". The conflict occurred in database "COPSDB", table "GraphiteGTCCore.YesNoQuestion", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

I'm Using a Microsoft Microsoft SQl Server 2012

The IsPrimary which is mentioned in the error Message is YesNoQuestion which is an Enumeration.

A Customer table contains Address which has a Property called "IsPrimary" it is a Required Field also I'm assigning the Value as Yes.  I found this Create Behaviour is Used in multiple places and it looks like it works fine everywhere

I tried it from different accounts and tried different assigning I know it is not much but this weird I cannot do much after that.

Ran a trace and got an exception in following query:

exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [COPS].[Address]([Name], [IsResidentialId], [StatusId], [IsPrimaryId], [CountryId], [TypeId], [EventRegistrationId], [ObjectId])
VALUES (@0, NULL, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6)
SELECT [Id], [TimeStamp]
FROM [COPS].[Address]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 nvarchar(40)',@0=N'DAVID STARR',@1=1,@2=0,@3=17,@4=1,@5=1138,@6=N'e0386866-51ea-438c-98f0-b172f325705e'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question to make it a bit more understandable? See [ask] for information on how to properly ask a question. Please give us some sample data and the things you have tried already. Tell us your [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_management_systems) as well since answers may be different for each DBMS. Help us help you!

Comment: please add the code of your loop, it could helps people here to help you

Comment: Also giving us some more information about the constraints you have there would be usefull.

Comment: There is a problem in your constraint... but unless you sure the code and data model it will be hard to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds to me as if you are trying to save a row in the database and either not providing a foreign key that is required, or an invalid foreign key for the customer. It is a bit hard to answer without more information, like an overview of the tables involved, and maybe some code :-)